# Laravel 9 getDriver(), getAdapter() and getClient() methods

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am working on an aws presigned url file uploader endpoint in Laravel. I had the code working in Laravel 8 but after Laravel 9, I get this error:

> Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::getAdapter()

How should I resolve this?

I read that I could add macros and other hacky solutions, but is there a new, "official" way to handle these?

This is my current code, that breaks:

```
$s3 = Storage::disk("s3_attachments");

$postObject = new PostObjectV4(
  $s3
    ->getDriver()
    ->getAdapter()
    ->getClient(),
  $s3
    ->getDriver()
    ->getAdapter()
    ->getBucket(),
  [
    ["acl" => "public-read"],
    ["starts-with", "\$key", $key],
    ["starts-with", "\$Content-Type", $file_type],
  ],
  [["content-length-range", $file_size, $file_size]],
  "+1 hours"
);
```

Comment: Not the official repository, but with Macro you're relating to this? https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/1118#issuecomment-1602849652

Comment: Yes, I tried to add "AwsS3V3Adapter::macro("getClient", function () {
      return $this->client;
    });" to my code, but it gives an error saying "Undefined property '$client'"

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by DI? Would it solve a problem? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, Frank (the maintainer of the lib) says to use DI or reflection.

> Either use reflection or get the adapter from your DI container, flysystem is not a service locator. *([ref](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/1642#issuecomment-1435696163))*

If you have a DI container ([Service Container in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/container)), then you will know to just call `get($key)` on it, but if not we can simply use reflection on the file system class, allowing us to access the private property `$adapter`:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(\get_class($filesystem));
$property = $reflection->getProperty('adapter');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$adapter = $property->getValue($object);
```

*(`setAccessible(true)` only necessary until PHP 8.0 (including); [ref](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/make-reflection-setaccessible-no-op))*